# math formulas in vbulletin forum

Tags: math, vbulletin, formulas

***Hello***,I have a vbulletin forum and i would like my users to be able to write math formulas in their posts (nice and easy), what is your suggestions?

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). I know that e.g. [Physics Forum](http://www.physicsforums.com) uses that in combination mit vBulletin.

Comment: I neither know nor have used a tutorial myself, but the most common configuration allows people to enter formulas in LaTeX style. Many of your users might know that already, and for the rest, a good LaTeX tutorial would help as well. Take [a random article from the Math StackExchange](https://dicestack.appspot.com/?site=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com&minscore=5&answerstatus=any) to see it in action. Click link repeatedly for several pages, in case the first didn't use formulas.